# How to preventing an input from being certain characters?

Tags: c, logic

Heres a portion of my code: I dont want the user input to be anything but A-Z, a-z, 1-9 and _. I don't know what I am doing wrong! Basically, if the user enters something that isnt those characters it will print an error. Ive been trying to debug this for a few hours and I feel I have only made things more "messy".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void get_outputfile(char *outname, int count_attempts);

FILE* CreateFile(){
   char name[20];
   char user_decision[1];
   int count_attempts=0;
   for(;;){
      get_outputfile(name, count_attempts);
      FILE *test;
      test = fopen(name,"r");
      if(test!=NULL){
         fclose(test);
         printf("file %s already exists, would you like to overwrite (Y/N)? ",name);
         scanf("%s",user_decision);
      }
      if(user_decision[0]!='Y'&&user_decision[0]!='y'){
         count_attempts=0;
         continue;
      }
      else{
         return fopen(name,"w");
      }
   }
   return 0;
}

void get_outputfile(char *outname, int count_attempts){
   int i;
   printf("Enter the output file name:");
   scanf("%s",outname);
   fgetc(stdin);
   for(i=0;i<strlen(outname);i++){
      if(((outname[i]<'a'||outname[i]>'z')&&(outname[i]<'A'||outname[i]>'Z')&&(outname[i]<'0'||outname[i]>'9'))&&(outname[i]!='_')){
         if (count_attempts>1){
            printf("You have exceeded maximum attempts. Restart the program and try again.\n");
            exit(0);
         }
         count_attempts++;
         printf("file name must be _, a-z, or A-Z\nEnter the output file name:");
         scanf("%s",outname);
         i=0;
      }
   }
   printf("returning..\n");
   return;
}

int main(){
   FILE* afile = CreateFile();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read more about [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) especially about the `"%["` format.

Comment: As for your current code, you should take a look at the [`isalnum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalnum) function. And think a little bit about your logic. Try to perform the checking logic on paper first. As a last resort, step through the code in a debugger while checking all variables and each expression (and sub-expression).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic in

```
  if(((outname[i]<'a'||outname[i]>'z')&&(outname[i]<'A'||outname[i]>'Z')&&(outname[i]<'0'||outname[i]>'9'))&&(outname[i]!='_')){
```

is wrong.

I suggest creating a function in which the logic can be simplified and easier to follow.

```
int isValidCharacter(char c)
{
   return ( (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || // Takes care of lower case letters
            (c >= 'A' && c <= 'A') || // Takes care of uppper case letters
            (c >= '0' && c <= '9') || // Takes care of numberss
            c == '_' );               // Takes care of _
}
```

and use it as:

```
  if ( !isValidCharacter(outname[i]) )
  {
     if (count_attempts>1){

     ...
```